# Shared configuration file format for both python and PHP

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, configuration-files, cross-language

I'm maintaining a project in PHP and I'm using a .php file (namely "config.php") to hold all my configuration parameters. The file itself defines a multilevel PHP array: so far all I have to do is `include()` it in my files.

Now I have to write some more scripts in python3, which must read the exact same configuration. I was thinking about YAML as a cross-language configuration file format, but do you guys have a better advice? I want to keep it simple and avoid XML and database.

*Edit: I see YAML is not included in standard PHP; what about JSON?*

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try it with `.ini` configuration files. You can parse these files natively to an php array with `parse_ini_file()`. I'm not very good in Python, but maybe this helps: [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

I do not recommend json, as it's not made to store configurations.

Comment: Interesting approach, I guess .INI is more readable.